# std::is_same for a not yet defined/declared class

Tags: c++, c++14

Is thw following code, a gcc bug?
Checking if T type is a not defined yet class Circle, returns false.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// uncomment to work
//struct Circle;

struct T_traits
{
    template<typename T>
    constexpr static id() { return is_same<T, class Circle>(); }
};


struct Circle{};

int main()
{
    cout << T_traits::id<Circle>() << "\r\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove `class`. You're declaring a new, different type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return is_same<T, class Circle>();
```

This will actually declare a local class called `Circle` when you comment out the global declaration. [basic.lookup.elab]/2:

> If the *elaborated-type-specifier* has no *nested-name-specifier*, and
>   unless the *elaborated-type-specifier* appears in a declaration with
>   the following form:
>         *class-key
>   attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *identifier* `;`
>    the
>   identifier is looked up according to 3.4.1 but ignoring any non-type
>   names that have been declared.[..]
>   **If the *elaborated-type-specifier* is introduced by the *class-key*
>   and this lookup does not find a previously declared *type-name*
>   [..] the *elaborated-type-specifier* is a declaration that
>   introduces the *class-name* as described in 3.3.2.**

The lookup is simple unqualified name lookup as defined in §3.4.1. Lookup is done in the definition context of `T_traits` as we are not dealing with dependent stuff, so the declaration of `Circle` right before `main` is never considered.
§3.3.2/7 (alias [basic.scope.pdecl]/7):

> The point of declaration of a class first declared in an
>   *elaborated-type-specifier* is as follows:
>
> - for an *elaborated-type-specifier* of the form
>
>   *class-key identifier*
>
>   if the *elaborated-type-specifier* is used in the
>     *decl-specifier-seq* or *parameter-declaration-clause* of a function defined in namespace scope, the identifier is declared as a
>     *class-name* in the namespace that contains the declaration; **otherwise**, except as a friend declaration, **the identifier is declared in the smallest namespace or block scope that contains the
>     declaration. [ *Note*: These rules also apply within templates. — *end
>     note* ]**

However, removing the `class` keyword won't work either - as mentioned before, the identifier isn't dependent and thus looked up in the definition context. If no declaration is found by this lookup, a diagnostic must be issued by the compiler - even if no specialization is instantiated.

Comment: [temp.res]/p10 requires a diagnostic if a nondependent name is not in scope at definition time.

Comment: @T.C. I think I saw that quote some time ago, but I didn't really memorize it. Cheers.